# How do I join these elements in a Nokogiri HTML scrape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to see how I can get the information from this screen scrape to join so that it can be put into a cvs or database file eventually in rails.  This is just an example but real data from a site I chose to test on.  I tested the css calls to make sure they are valid.  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Code follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://neighbors.whitepages.com/search/neighbor_search/7707-Gralnick-Pl/Springfield,-VA"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("title").text
doc.css(".header").each do |header|
  address = header.css(".address").text
  puts "#{address}"
end
doc.css(".household_members").each do |household_members|  
  names = household_members.css(".basic_info").text
  puts "#{names}" 
end
```

Comment: Join them how? How do you want the data to be formatted?

Comment: The data is already grouped into divs, you just need to iterate over each div.

Comment: Initially I was just going to put the address in one column and the first name that corresponded to it in a names column. Ultimately all the names in separate columns up to 4 with the address and continue to process row by row to a cvs file or table.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but unfortunately my limited experience has not allowed me to find a solution to the original formatting/collection issue.  An example of what is being discussed would be helpful.  I am looking at a work around but would like to understand the proper way to deal with this nesting with many issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the data in a more usable format. It loops around the outer containing `<div class="single">`, allowing easier grouping of the address and people:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://neighbors.whitepages.com/search/neighbor_search/7707-Gralnick-Pl/Springfield,-VA"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
data = doc.search('div.single').map{ |div|
  [
    div.at('.address').text,
    div.search('.household_members > .basic_info').map{ |n| n.text.strip }
  ]
}
```

Looking at `data[0, 5]`:

```
[
  ["7705 Gralnick Pl", ["Debra A Mussmon"]],
  ["7709 Gralnick Pl", ["Mary D Apker", "John E Apker"]],
  ["7202 Caulking Pl", ["Vivianjune S Furber"]],
  ["9246 Northedge Dr", ["Bridget Cox (703) 455-6057", "Joseph R Furber (703) 455-2442", "Vivian J Furber (703) 455-2442"]],
  ["9244 Northedge Dr", ["David B Burlingame (703) 455-5708", "Linda J Burlingame (703) 455-5708", "Colby Burlingame (703) 455-5708"]]
]
```

Without any hint at your database schema its impossible to give you any help writing to your DB, but at least this gives you a starting point. Iterate over the `data` array of arrays, and for each sub-array store the address, then the associated names.

If you want to do something with the phone numbers you'll have to figure out how to capture them using a regular expression, but that's a separate question.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I had resolved getting the data into the array but your code is much more eloquent.  Thank you.  The model at this point will simply capture the array as you have shown with the full address and each name as separate fields.  May have to "chomp" out the telephones as they are not necessary at this point. It  will be a flat table with a link to other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the `div`s with `id` =~ `group_` and/or `class` `group`.

Then within each `div` extract the address and household members.